# Jquery Current radio button click it disable in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I am fetching value from database which append to radio button in **[jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)** like

```
formatter: function (cellValue, option){
    return '<input type="radio" name="subradio" id="subradio"/>';
}
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    getcurrpatta(rowid);
},
```

Now, the radio button populates if I click a radio.  One function has been called.  But if I click the same radio button again it has to disable no function call again then i go for other click radio button the old one have to enable how to do this???

Answer (score 0):

This is the javascript code

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('input').removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p1rempub/)

Comment: working fine but first radio button cant disable at first time .further radio button works good am checking on it....

Comment: When you click the first radio, it is not disable?